# Prove a finite commutative ring is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, noetherian

I was asked to prove that every finite, commutative ring is Noetherian.

My attempt:

Let $R$ be a finite ring.
Let $I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq I_3....$ be a chain of ideals of $R$. Since $R$ is finite, with $K$ member, the number of ideals on $R$ is finite, at most $2^K$.
Consider the two cases:

(1) For all  $i\neq j$ , $I_i\neq I_j$.
Therefore, the chain must stabilise and become constant, for otherwise, we would have more than $2^K$ ideals, absurd.

(2) For all $i\neq j$, $I_i= I_j$. This is trivial.

Note, (1) automatically implies that if there exists $i\neq j$, then $I_i\neq I_j$. Hence we are done.

Is the logic correct?

Comment: you mean *Noetherian*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yup.

Comment: Aside of minor glitches, there is one more case to consider: when there are some $I_i=I_j$ and some other $I_{i'}\ne I_{j'}$. But in fact you do not need any subcases. Just count those $i$ for which $I_i\subsetneqq I_{i+1}$: there might be only finitely many such $i$.